# How to inject templating into Symfony 4 service

Tags: dependency-injection, symfony4

I have a Symfony 4 service that requires templating. I can inject other services like

```
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
```

And in the service constructor

```
public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
{
    $this->logger = $logger;
}
```

Which class should i have to import?

Answer (score 3):

I found how to get the templating component

`use Twig\Environment;`

This is how my class look now

And in the constructor

```
public function __construct(Environment $templating, LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->templating = $templating;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }
```